# What are the screen resolution sizes for android sizes

Tags: android

```
ldpi    
mdpi    
hdpi    
xhdpi   
xxhdpi  
xxxhdpi
```

Ok my question is about setting resolution size of background image

Lets what are the sizes for land mode ?

for example : xxhdpi : 1920x1080 is this correct ? and the rest goes how ?

thank you very much

Comment: The list that you have there is a screen density list, not sizes. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a linear relation between screen density and screen size. There are multiple screen dimension configurations for each screen density value.

For example, you can have two hdpi devices, one being 569x320px and another 800x400px.

Your density factor represents how many pixels are needed to make one dpi or dip (density independent pixel).

So, for example, hdpi has a 1.5 density factor, meaning that each dpi is made of 1.5 pixels.

As for xhdpi, it has a 2.0 factor, this is, 1 dpi = 2px.

See more at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [also this one](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the android devices screen resolution sizes with additional details in both landscape and portrait mode

as

1. dpi of the device
2. Title bar height
3. Status Bar height
4. Content View

Refer [ScreenDeviceStatistics](http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php).